# How to show div as popup on click of anchor tag?

Tags: jquery

I want to show `div` as popup on-click of an anchor tag image.
I have one main image and four vertical thumbnails side of image.

On the main image, top corner one anchor tag image is there. Upon clicking on this image, I want whole main image and its thumbnails to show in popup.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, jQuery core doesn't have any method to show a modal\pop up.

You can achieve your request in vanilla JavaScript in this way:

```
<a id="picture1" data-id="1" href="#" onclick="showDialog(this);">
    <!-- your img or whatever -->
</a>

<dialog id="pictureDialog">
    <!-- your dialog content -->
</dialog>

<script>
    function showDialog(element) {
        var id = e.getAttribute("data-id");
        //do some setup for your dialog
        document.getElementById("pictureDialog").showModal(); 
    } 
</script>
```

Remaining in jQuery family, You can simply open a modal using jQuery UI:
http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog

Or adding a framework of your flavor, like Bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals